# How to inspect the raw contents of a partition?

Tags: shell, partition, dd

I'm trying to see the contents in raw bytes of a dummy partition `/dev/sda3`, which I've made to be `100MiB` through gparted.

I want to test writing and reading on that partition. Is there a tool that can be used for manual inspection ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same tools that you can use for other files (generally) can also be used on block devices. This means that you can use, for example, `xxd` or `hexdump` to inspect the filesystem:

```
$ sudo xxd /dev/sda2 | head -10
00000000: eb58 9053 5953 4c49 4e55 5800 0200 0000  .X.SYSLINUX.....
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 3f00 ff00 0008 2000  ........?..... .
00000020: 00f8 1f06 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 fafc 31c9 8ed1  ............1...
00000060: bc76 7b52 0657 1e56 8ec1 b126 bf78 7bf3  .v{R.W.V...&.x{.
00000070: a58e d9bb 7800 0fb4 370f a056 20d2 781b  ....x...7..V .x.
00000080: 31c0 b106 893f 8947 02f3 64a5 8a0e 187c  1....?.G..d....|
00000090: 884d f850 5050 50cd 13eb 628b 55aa 8b75  .M.PPPP...b.U..u
```

The same goes for writing. For example, using `dd` (you probably don't want to do this):

```
$ sudo dd of=/dev/sda2 skip=... bs=... <<< 'a string'
```